# PHP PDO ODBC SELECT returns partial results

Tags: php, select, pdo, odbc

```
$db_a = new PDO("odbc:MYOB",'user','pass');

foreach($db_a->query("SELECT * FROM Sale WHERE SaleID = 108605") as $row) {
echo '<pre>';
print_r($row);
echo '</pre>';
}
```

This returns all the table column titles as well as the first five results but everything after that is blank. I've tried issuing the same select statement through MS access and it works correctly

```
Array
(
    [ItemSaleLineID] => 1605696
    [0] => 1605696
    [SaleLineID] => 1605696
    [1] => 1605696
    [SaleID] => 108605
    [2] => 108605
    [LineNumber] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [LineTypeID] => D
    [4] => D
    [Description] => 
    [5] => 
    [TaxExclusiveTotal] => 
    [6] => 
    [TaxInclusiveTotal] => 
    [7] => 
    [TaxCodeID] => 
    [8] => 
    [JobID] => 
    [9] => 
    [IsMultipleJob] => 
    [10] => 
    [Quantity] => 
    [11] => 
    [ItemID] => 
    [12] => 
    [TaxExclusiveUnitPrice] => 
    [13] => 
    [TaxInclusiveUnitPrice] => 
    [14] => 
    [Discount] => 
    [15] => 
    [CostOfGoodsSoldAmount] => 
    [16] => 
    [LocationID] => 
    [17] => 
    [Kit/ComponentIndicator] => 
    [18] => 
)
```

Output from var_dump:

```
array(20) { ["SaleLineID"]=> string(7) "1605696" [0]=> string(7) "1605696" ["SaleID"]=> string(6) "108605" [1]=> string(6) "108605" ["LineNumber"]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "1" ["LineTypeID"]=> string(1) "D" [3]=> string(1) "D" ["Description"]=> NULL [4]=> NULL ["TaxExclusiveAmount"]=> NULL [5]=> NULL ["TaxInclusiveAmount"]=> NULL [6]=> NULL ["TaxCodeID"]=> NULL [7]=> NULL ["JobID"]=> NULL [8]=> NULL ["IsMultipleJob"]=> NULL [9]=> NULL } array(20) { ["SaleLineID"]=> string(7) "1605697" [0]=> string(7) "1605697" ["SaleID"]=> string(6) "108605" [1]=> string(6) "108605" ["LineNumber"]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "2" ["LineTypeID"]=> string(1) "D" [3]=> string(1) "D" ["Description"]=> NULL [4]=> NULL ["TaxExclusiveAmount"]=> NULL [5]=> NULL ["TaxInclusiveAmount"]=> NULL [6]=> NULL ["TaxCodeID"]=> NULL [7]=> NULL ["JobID"]=> NULL [8]=> NULL ["IsMultipleJob"]=> NULL [9]=> NULL } array(20) { ["SaleLineID"]=> string(7) "1605698" [0]=> string(7) "1605698" ["SaleID"]=> string(6) "108605" [1]=> string(6) "108605" ["LineNumber"]=> string(1) "3" [2]=> string(1) "3" ["LineTypeID"]=> string(1) "D" [3]=> string(1) "D" ["Description"]=> NULL [4]=> NULL ["TaxExclusiveAmount"]=> NULL [5]=> NULL ["TaxInclusiveAmount"]=> NULL [6]=> NULL ["TaxCodeID"]=> NULL [7]=> NULL ["JobID"]=> NULL [8]=> NULL ["IsMultipleJob"]=> NULL [9]=> NULL }
```

Comment: Try `var_dump` instead of `print_r` and show those results (it shows type/length information instead of just structure).

Comment: Generally it's a bad idea to loop right over the `PDOStatement` object as it can return `boolean` false, which can't be looped over. Not to mention it should only be used with a query that has no dynamic input into it.  So if you want to do `SaleID = :SaleID` later you will have to redo you code anyway.

Comment: How do you know that data even exists, did you look in PhpMyAdmin?  I never seen data magically disappear this way. `Output from var_dump:` you can do better then that `echo "<pre>"; var_dump($data);` then when you put it in here select it and press ctrl+k to turn it to code.

Comment: I've checked with MS Access and all the data is their. Every cell has a value.